# Calculating wait time on one-lane road with two-way travel using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

I want to know how to calculate the wait time on a single-track/one-lane road (only room for one car at a time) for one car waiting for another car to pass by.

For example, two cars drive on the one-lane road in opposition to each other. When the two cars meet in the road, one car should wait for the other car to pass.

I wonder if Network Analyst (especially, Vehicle Routing Problem) can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think the vehicle routing problem will allow two-way travel on a one-way designated road.

Comment: This isn't exactly a designated one-way road, it's a road that is only wide enough for one vehicle to travel at a time. (Not sure what the term for that would be, OR whether Network Analyst could cope.)

Comment: Erica was right. That's what I was trying to say. Thank you for correcting me on that. "it's a road that is only wide enough for one vehicle to travel at a time."

Comment: Please give us a more precise characterization of the "wait time." Could it be (a) the time for the opposing car to traverse the track, (b) the average time for cars to recognize each other, back up, and allow one to pass, (c) the expected time to wait based on a frequency distribution of cars on this stretch of road (which would account for the times when no waiting is necessary), or (d) something else?

Comment: As whuber's options point out this is more a traffic than network problem. The network edge can have a penalty requiring longer travel time than normal distance/speed, but that might vary depending on the amount of traffic/time of day. It wouldn't be a single, uniform penalty unless you did some averaging calculations and chose to make it such. Any network solver is going to look at a specific set of network conditions, be it the 2pm (no traffic, no penalty) or 5pm (an extra 5 minutes for rush hour). VRP just decides whether or not to use that edge - not how long it will take.

Comment: This question appears to be dependent on the answer to a more focussed but later one from the same asker: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110725/modelling-two-way-single-track-one-lane-width-road-in-arcgis-network-analyst

Comment: This and your other question seem to me as true traffic engineering problems rather than GIS ones. there are a lot of factors involved in such an analysis, such as arrival rate, speeds, type of traffic control, acceptable levels of service, peakhour factors, etc.

Comment: For this questions to attract a potential answerer I think it should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.