# Modelling two-way single-track/one-lane width road in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network-analyst

I don't know how make one-lane roads(only room for one car at a time) for one car waiting for another car to pass by in ArcGIS.

Yesterday, I asked about the wait time when the two cars meet in the road, one car should wait for the other car to pass that as [Calculating wait time on one-lane road with two-way travel using ArcGIS Network Analyst?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110526/how-to-calculate-wait-time-on-a-one-lane-road-with-two-way-travel)

But I realized that I can't even make a one-lane road...

How can I make this road in ArcGIS Network analyst (especially, VRP (Vehicle Routing Problem))?